# Can’t download file using service account for file that was uploaded by another non-service account

Tags: google-drive-api, service-accounts, google-workspace

I'm struggling with a permissions problem in Google Drive. I have a google account (e.g. blah@domain.co.uk) that's part of an organisation. At the organisation level is a rule that prevents certain files being shared outside of the organisation. Within the blah@domain.co.uk is a service account with owner permissions. Using the Google Drive API v3 I can upload and download files to the organisations' Drive using the service account. If I manually upload a file (via the Web) using the blah@domain.co.uk account, I can't download the file via the API using the Google Drive API. I receive the following exception:-

> Google.GoogleApiException   HResult=0x80131500
>   Message=Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError File not found: . [404] Errors [   Message[File not found: ]
>   Location[fileId - parameter] Reason[notFound] Domain[global] ]

My guess is that because the service account (serviceaccount@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com) is outside of the organisation that the rule defined at the organisation level is preventing the service account downloading the file. But, that is a guess.

The folder that files are uploaded to and downloaded from has been shared to the service account with organise, add and edit.

Looking for ideas how to work around this…define a custom security policy to define an exception for the service account?

Comment: 404 Errors generally mean file doesn't exists to be found. In your case if the file exists and if there was a permission/access level issue then unauthorized access should have been issued. So, I request you to go through the error code of Google Drive API. If you are sure about access being the problem, then you need to create the exception case in the pre-set policy.

Comment: by organization do you mean gusite?

Comment: Yes, by organisation I did mean gsuite. Anyway, I have managed to resolve this and it was as I had guessed - the rule at the organisation level preventing sharing of PII data outside of the organisation. The resolution was to add a group to the organisation that allowed accounts outside of the organisation to be members of the group. I added the service account to the group and then added the group as an exemption to the PII rule.